# Rails 7 missing partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I am upgrading to Rails 7.1 and get a weird error in a view using a JS partial:

> Missing partial account/_stripe.js.erb, application/_stripe.js.erb
> with {:locale=>[:fr], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[],
> :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}.

Here is my code to render the partial (it works well with Rails 6):

```
<%= render "stripe.js.erb" %>
```

The partial is located in the same folder as the view and is named "_stripe.js.erb".

I tried to replace the name of the partial, as suggested, by `account/stripe`, `account/stripe.js`, `account/stripe.js.erb`, `stripe`, `stripe.js`, none works.

Any idea how to solve this with Rails 7? Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Having an extension in the partial name was deprecated in Rails 6.1 and removed in Rails 7. You should use the following syntax:

```
<%= render partial: 'stripe', formats: :js %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works!

Comment: Thanks for the answer @AbM. Where can that deprecation warning be found? I'm not seeing it listed in the 6.1 release notes: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/6_1_release_notes.html I ask because I'd like to know about things like this when they are just deprecation not bugs :) Thanks again!

Comment: @JaredMenard It was introduced in this [PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/39164). Not sure if it is mentioned somewhere else. I ran into the deprecation warning when running integration tests

Comment: Where did you find information on the options to pass to render partial? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: According to the rails 7.1.2 guide they are still showing examples with .html.erb extensions. Where is it documented that this should no longer be done please?
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html