# Rails not able to find partial

Tags: javascript, json, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jbuilder

I have a folder structure like

```
project/app/views/api/users/_user.json.jbuilder
```

The error is

```
Searched in:
  * "/Users/name/Desktop/etc/etc/project/app/views"

ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing partial api/users/_user.json.jbuilder with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}.
```

I'm trying to render

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.currentUser = <%= render("api/users/user.json.jbuilder",
        user: current_user).html_safe %>
  </script>
```

The exact same code worked in Rails 5.xx, but I'm on Rails 7.xx now and I'm stuck on this error.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 7, including the extension on the file results in an error.

```
<%= render partial: "api/users/user", 
    formats: [:json], 
    handlers: [:jbuilder],
    locals: { user: current_user } %>
```

Works and Rails is able to find the partial. The error message is pretty useless in this case because it just seems like you're doing it right. Also, I can't find any documentation at all on the options hash you're supposed to pass to render partial. My Github Copilot just auto-completed it for me, then I scoured the internet trying to find information pertaining to it but couldn't.

I'm assuming you just look at the error message

```
{:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}
```

Then realize the options are locale, formats, variants, handlers?

Answer found here [Rails 7 missing partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71069354/rails-7-missing-partial)

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#options-for-render

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alex! Damn, that's a harsh lesson learned for me; read the official documentation rather than just googling and hoping for a quick answer. I guess the answer was right there in the official docs in front of my eyes this whole time

Answer (score 1):

To build on the answer above. If you were to replace

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.currentUser =
      <%= render("api/users/user.json.jbuilder", 
        user: current_user).html_safe %>      
  </script>
```

with

```
<script
  <%= render partial: "api/users/user", 
    formats: [:json], 
    handlers: [:jbuilder],
    locals: { user: current_user } %>
</script>
```

You would still run into a pretty annoying error because the latter doesn't have the html safe tail

```
.html_safe!
```

the way I understand it is that html safe is frowned upon and should be substituted for sanitize to get the same result as the original code.

```
<script id="bootstrap-current-user" type="text/javascript">       
  window.currentUser = 
  <%= sanitize render partial: 'api/users/user',
    formats: :json,
    handlers: :jbuilder,
    locals: {user: current_user} %>      
</script>
```

If you don't sanitize the partial call before assigning it to the window.current user then you will get a syntax error from jbuilder trying to use &quot instead of a "

[Here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/String:html_safe) is the html_safe documentation.

[Here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html) is the sanitation documentation.